# Show this function is Lipschitz

Tags: calculus, continuity, lipschitz-functions

Consider the following function

$$f(x)= 
\begin{cases}
e^{x/2}  \qquad x \leq 0 \\
x + e^{-x} \qquad x >0 
\end{cases}$$

I need to show it's Lipschitz with constant $1$: $|T(x)-T(y)|<|x-y|$. For $x,y >0$ and $x,y \leq 0$ I can prove it easily.

But, if $x>0$ and $y<0$, then $$|T(x) - T(y)| = |e^{x/2} - y - e^{-y}|$$ and I don't know how to move from here. Any hint?

Comment: The function $f$ is absolutely continuous, so
$$
f(x)-f(y)=\int_y^x f'(t)\,dt
$$
and $|f'(t)|\le 1$ almost everywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $x>0$ and $y<0$, then by the cases for $x,y\ge0$ and $x,y\le0$ we have
$$|T(x)-T(y)|\le|T(x)-T(0)|+|T(0)-T(y)|\le |x-0|+|0-y|=x-y.$$

Comment: You should have in the last inequality $|x| +|-y|$... which is not what you want to show. @David

Comment: @bobinthebox: Look again. $x$ is positive and $y$ is negative. So $|x| = x-0$ and $|-y| = 0-y$.

Comment: Ah right, so you use the fact that $x-y=|x-y|$ as $x-y>0$. Thanks, my bad @MartinR and David